# Converting pointer to A into a pointer to structure B that A is embedded inside

Tags: c, pintos

In Pintos project, there is a macro that converting pointer like what I wrote in title.

```
#define list_entry(LIST_ELEM, STRUCT, MEMBER)
                     ((STRUCT *) ((uint8_t *) &(LIST_ELEM)->next
                     - offsetof (STRUCT, MEMBER.next)))
```

(at src/lib/kernel/list.h)

Why It is not like this?

```
#define list_entry(LIST_ELEM, STRUCT, MEMBER)
                     ((STRUCT *) ((uint8_t *)LIST_ELEM
                     - offsetof (STRUCT, MEMBER)))
```

Comment: It could be becaue of the idiom to have one unused element at the start of a linked list (for simplification of certain list operations).

Comment: List_elem is not a pointer